# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/rules/TestRule on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I am getting this error only when I try to build through the command line. When I try to run and debug, the test case passes.

Comment: So it works in intelliJ, but not on the command line? Therefore that class is on the classpath in intelliJ and not from your command window. Have you tried using the -cp command line flag to specify classpath? i.e. java -cp xxxxx MyClass where xxxxx is your classpath. The classpath can include wildcards to specify while directories.

Comment: I mean it works fine when I give a run or a debug but it does not work when I give a build on IntelliJ terminal

Comment: What command/tool do you use to build from the command line? Where do you have JUnit jars located? How do you include this classpath when building from the command line?